# How to make a contour/density plot of a large 2D scatter plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot, contour, density-plot

I have an overcrowded scatter plot and I'm trying to create a contour or density plot to see if there is any distinct populations in my data. I have tried the following code but I get the error:

> too many values to unpack (expected 2)

My code is:

```
x = CDM_300[:,[1]]
y = CDM_300[:,[2]]

# Evaluate a gaussian kde on a regular grid of nbins x nbins over data extents
nbins=300
k = kde.gaussian_kde([x,y])
xi, yi = np.mgrid[x.min():x.max():nbins*1j, y.min():y.max():nbins*1j]
zi = k(np.vstack([xi.flatten(), yi.flatten()]))

# Make the plot
plt.pcolormesh(xi, yi, zi.reshape(xi.shape))
plt.show()

# Change color palette
plt.pcolormesh(xi, yi, zi.reshape(xi.shape), cmap=plt.cm.Greens_r)
plt.show()
```

`CDM_300` is a (23800, 3) array, if I try to `np.meshgrid` the data, my laptop just crashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to arise from the way you have indexed the data. When you do `[:, [1]]`, the shape of your data becomes `(23800, 1)` and each element is an array in itself.

Use the following indexing **without** the extra `[]` around the second index.

```
x = CDM_300[:, 1]
y = CDM_300[:, 2]
```